# Filter an object in Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am very new to Laravel and php and i am facing an issue with a collection. The collection is generated in this way:

```
$users = $media->campaign->users;
```

Which return this data:

```
[{id: 1, name: "name", suspended: 0},{id: 2, name: "name2", suspended: 1}]
```

How can i filter this object in laravel 4.1 to get only the elements that have 0 as suspended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_filter(array $array[, callable $callback[, int $flag]])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
array_filter($users, function($value) {
    return($value->suspended === 0);
});
```

Check more in [Laravel 4.2 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#collections), Taylor wrote there that filtering collections use `array_filter` function. Also you should can use `$users = $users->filter(function($user) {});` method.

Also, thanks to @xAoc, you can use filtering on SQL query:

```
$users = $media->campaign
    ->users()
    ->where("suspended", "=", 0)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Will be faster if using mysql filtering `$media->campaign->users()->where("suspended", "=", 0)->get();` but your answer also ok :)

Comment: That's true, I forgot about query to SQL!

Comment: I just tried the first option and got this: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given'

Comment: array filter won't work because Laravel returns a `Collection`. For applying array_filter a function, you need transform `Collection` to `array`.

Comment: @Leon done | @xAoc thats why I mentioned second solution (`$users->filter()`) which works like `array_filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing a direct "equals" comparison, Laravel's Collection has a `where()` method you can use. For example:

```
$users = $media->campaign->users;
$users->where('suspended', 0);
```

This is a good option if you already have the Collection. If, however, you have control over generating the Collection, it would be more beneficial to only get the actual data you're looking for. In this case, you can add the where clause to the SQL statement, so you will only retrieve the final records you want. For example:

```
$users = $media->campaign->users()->where('suspended', '=', 0);
```

NB: the `where()` method on the Collection and the `where()` method on the query builder have different signatures. The query builder lets you pass in an operator to use ('=', '>', '<', etc). The Collection only does a direct equals comparison. This trips up a lot of people.